# Why are there two called "Python” and "Python launcher” seperately?

Tags: python, module

I am on a Mac OS. Why are there two of them "Python" and the other one on top is 'Python launcher’.

image - (file:///Users/Buddhikawijegunarathna/Desktop/Screenshot%202022-03-28%20at%203.22.27%20PM.png)

What is the difference?

"Python launcher" is in Applications/python 3.10/Python launcher
(the current version I use of python is 3.11)

"python" is in the Macintosh `HD/library/frameworks/python.frameworks/resources/python` app

I can't run python files that use modules using 'Python launcher' but can using the ‘Python' app.

And I can run a python file from anywhere, maybe desktop or in a folder or anything by using 'Python launcher’, but in ‘Python' app it either works in the desktop or a specific place, and strictly not inside folders. (if I run, it's displaying an error as the directory cannot be found.)

Comment: `the current version I use of python is 3.11` Are you sure?  I thought Python was only up to version 3.10.

Comment: How did you install Python? It looks like you have at least two python installs

Comment: Also, it does no good to give us the filename for an image that is only on your computer...

Comment: "Are you sure? I thought Python was only up to version 3.10” yeah, but I accidentally downloaded a pre release. its the sixth of the seven alpha releases. I didn't mean to download. is that a problem? I mean, will it be problamatic?

Answer (score -1):

`Python` is a computer language, also means an overall of the whole Python system;

While `Python Launcher` is an executable file which launches Python compiler & functions when you use Python.